# Using a string to generate a byte array of data from a lookup table

Tags: c#, arrays

I have this program that is reading the test string from a `textbox` and convert it to a byte array that makeup data to be diplayed on a screen. I am getting very close. The code can currently pull the text, convert it to a char array, and then replace the zeros in the byte array with useful data from a 2 dimensional array that contains 5 bits for all the letters of the alphabet. I am have a problem though. The code only seems to run once. If I click the button a second time I end up with an "indexOutOfRange exception unhandled." Also it only seems to work for one letter at a time

EX: if I type "A" it will display, but if I type "AA" I get the same error. 
Here is the WordArray[]

```
byte[,] Letters = new byte[18, 5] { { 63, 72, 72, 63, 0 },
                                       { 127, 73, 73, 54, 0 },
                                       { 63, 72, 72, 63, 0 },
                                       { 127, 73, 73, 54, 0 },
                                       { 63, 72, 72, 63, 0 },
                                       { 127, 73, 73, 54, 0 }, 
                                       { 63, 72, 72, 63, 0 },
                                       { 127, 73, 73, 54, 0 }, 
                                       { 63, 72, 72, 63, 0 }, 
                                       { 127, 73, 73, 54, 0 },
                                       { 63, 72, 72, 63, 0 },
                                       { 127, 73, 73, 54, 0 },
                                       { 63, 72, 72, 63, 0 },
                                       { 127, 73, 73, 54, 0 }, 
                                       { 63, 72, 72, 63, 0 },
                                       { 127, 73, 73, 54, 0 },
                                       { 63, 72, 72, 63, 0 },
                                       { 127, 73, 73, 54, 0 } };
```

Here is the `click_button` method:

```
    int Aindex = 0;
    int LettersIndex = 0;
    private void SendButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WordIndex = 0;
        if (Aindex > 0)
        {
            Aindex = 0;
        }
        string CurrentTextString = textBox1.Text;
        char[] charArray = CurrentTextString.ToCharArray();
        if (textBox1.Text == "")
        {

        }
        else
        {
            foreach (char c in charArray)
            {
                int index = 0;
                CharAsciiArray[index] = Convert.ToChar((Convert.ToInt32(c)));
                textBox2.Text += CharAsciiArray[index] + " ";
                charCount++;
                index++;
            }
            for (int NumberofBytes = 0; NumberofBytes < charCount; NumberofBytes++)
            {

                LettersIndex = 0;
                // int currentChar = CharAsciiArray[index] - 65;
                //textBox2.Text += currentChar;
                int currentCharAscii = (CharAsciiArray[Aindex]);
                int currentChar = currentCharAscii - 'A';
                for (int NumberofBits = 0; NumberofBits < 5; NumberofBits++)
                {


                    // textBox2.Text += currentChar;
                    WordArray[WordIndex + 3] = Letters[currentChar, LettersIndex];
                    textBox2.Text += WordArray[WordIndex] + " ";
                    LettersIndex++;
                    WordIndex++;
                }
                Aindex++;
            }
            SendingData = true;
            //SendNextByte();

            serialPort1.Write(WordArray, 0, WordArray.Length);
        }
    }
```

Comment: which line causes the exception?

Comment: The line containing "WordArray[WordIndex + 3] = Letters[currentChar, LettersIndex]; " is thowing the error

Comment: Where do you declare `WordArray[]`? And assign content to it?

Comment: WordArray[] is a global array delcared at the top level of the program.. I will add it above.

Comment: When it crashes, what are the values of `WordIndex`, `currentChar`, and `LettersIndex`? At least one of those is going to be out of range. You should be able to examine those when it crashes. If not, write an exception handler that will catch that exception and output those three values so that you can inspect them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following loop

```
  foreach (char c in charArray)
  {
      int index = 0;
      CharAsciiArray[index] = Convert.ToChar((Convert.ToInt32(c)));
      textBox2.Text += CharAsciiArray[index] + " ";
      charCount++;
      index++;
  }
```

You apparently want to increase the index on each iteration but you're resetting index to 0 every time.

Besides that, make up your mind on what pattern you want to follow when naming your variables. For instance:

Why is `AIndex` not `AnIndex` and how would you name the next index? `AnotherIndex`? Does it need to be global? Why does `charArray` start with a lowercase c and `NumberOfBytes` with an uppercase N? Write code as if you would have to explain it to your wife / husband (who knows?) and it'll be easier to maintain / debug.